# How do I open python profile data with kCacheGrind?

Tags: python, django, cprofile, kcachegrind, django-extensions

I am having trouble examining profile data with qcachegrind on mac.I am using django-extensions to generate the profile data.  I am able to open a normal profile log using cProfile in the code with `pyprof2calltree`, but i cannot open the output generated from `/manage.py runprofileserver --prof-path=profile_data --use-cprofile --kcachegrind`. Has anybody successfully managed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with --kcachegrind , you can open it with QCachegrind(for Qt or KCachegrind for KDE env).
download it from http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html